# Reinforcement learning - state space and action space

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am working on a reinforcement learning strategy for parameter control of a local search heuristic.

The complete state for this RL problem can be defined as $S = \{s, p\}$, where $s$ and $p$ are respectively the current solution and the vector of current parameter values.

An action correponds to raplacing or maintaining the vector of parameters $p$ with a new configuration.

Since the above formulation of the state space is impractical, would it be reasonable to represent the state only as $S = p$? In this case, the state space basically becomes equivalent to the action space.